# Can this recursive function work without the `trav` pointer

Tags: c, recursion, cs50, trie

I was working on a pset4 speller using tries. This function gives the size of a dictionary loaded as a trie. Can this function work without using the `trav` pointer which I am using? Do I have to point to the previous location or is this unnecessary?

Will my location be remembered in a function call and every time I recursively call a function the pointer to sizer will only be something specific to that call? And once I return the control back to the previous function, will it run on the previous location before I called the recursive function OR do I have to point it specifically to the previous location?

```
unsigned int size(void)
{    
    node *trav = root;
    int ctr = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {       
            //Sizer is also a node pointer initialized to root globally
            if (sizer -> children[i] == NULL)
            {
                continue;

            }
            else
            {   
                //Store the current value of sizer 
                trav = sizer;

                //Change sizer to point to its child
                sizer = sizer -> children[i];

                if ((sizer -> is_word) == true)
                {
                    ctr ++;
                }
                // recursively call size again
                int x = size();
                ctr += x;

                /*After adding the number all the words IN THE CHILDREN
                  of this particular child, I want to point to the 
                  original `sizer`, so that i can move on to the next 
                  child and repeat the same for its chidren. To do that 
                  i need something to point back to original position
                */
                sizer = trav;

            }

    }

    return ctr;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can this function work without using the trav pointer which i am using .

Well... no, not this function. The problem here is that `sizer` is global so when you want the code to change it and later restore it, you will need an extra variable to store the value before its changed.

However, why use a global variable?

If you pass the pointer to the "current root", you can avoid `trav` and you get a more clean design without global variables.

Something like:

```
unsigned int size(node *sizer)
{    
    unsigned int ctr = 0;       // notice: changed to unsigned to match the return type
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {       
        if (sizer -> children[i] != NULL)
        {
            if ((sizer->children[i]->is_word) == true)
            {
                ctr ++;
            }
            // recursively call size again while passing sizer->children[i]
            ctr += size(sizer->children[i]);
        }
    }

    return ctr;
}
```

Now every recursive call has its own `sizer` variable so you never need to change `sizer` and consequently you don't need to store into a `trav`variable.